# Duplicate arrays object value create as multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I wanted to create filter from object, which passed from from, but there can be multiple values from filter form. 
I want to pass an array to my filter and if theres multiple values, it can be multi-dimensional array.

For example, from form with `serializeArray` it's pass

```
0: {name: "holiday", value: "newyear"}
1: {name: "holiday", value: "christmas"}
2: {name: "startDate", value: ""}
3: {name: "genre", value: ""}
4: {name: "city", value: ""}
```

But I wanted to create

```
0: {name: "holiday", value: {"christmas", "newyear"}}
1: {name: "startDate", value: ""}
2: {name: "genre", value: ""}
3: {name: "city", value: ""}
```

And then pass it to `filter()` by my own rules and keys

I wanted to ask, how to validate, that there is multiple values with duplicate `name` property, and create new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to group values in object and then get an array with `Object.values`.

```js
const data = [{name: "holiday", value: "newyear"}, {name: "holiday", value: "christmas"}, {name: "startDate", value: ""}, {name: "genre", value: ""}, {name: "city", value: ""}]

const obj = data.reduce((r, e) => {
  if(!r[e.name]) r[e.name] = {...e}
  else r[e.name].value = [].concat(r[e.name].value, e.value)
  return r
}, {})

const result = Object.values(obj)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by name and then extract the grouped values.

```js
let arr =[{name: "holiday", value: "newyear"},{name: "holiday", value: "christmas"},{name: "startDate", value: ""},{name: "genre", value: ""},{name: "city", value: ""}],
    result = Object.values(arr.reduce((a, {name, value: v}) => {
      (a[name] || (a[name] = {name, value: []})).value.push(v);
      return a;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```